# Dojo and Ajax - rendering widgets

Tags: javascript, ajax, dojo, dijit.layout

I'm trying to load content into a Dojo content pane in a specific html tag and not replace the entire content pane. The html I'm loading includes a markup defined widget that I'd like to have rendered when the new row is loaded.

So, I have a table that is being dynamically filled via ajax,ie:

```
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.5/dojo/dojo.xd.js" 
     djConfig="parseOnLoad: true, isDebug:true"></script>
  <div id="table-pane" dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane">
    <table class="test">
      <tbody>
        <tr><td>Name</td><td>Year</td><td>Age</td></tr>
        <tr>
          <td><span dojoType="dijit.InlineEditBox" editor="dijit.form.Textarea">Mike</span>
          </td>
          <td>2010</td>
          <td>12</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

<script>
var html ='<tr><td><span dojoType="dijit.InlineEditBox" editor="dijit.form.Textarea">John</span></td><td>2011</td><td>22</td></tr>';
dojo.require("dijit.layout.ContentPane");
dojo.require("dijit.InlineEditBox");
dojo.require("dijit.form.Textarea");
dojo.addOnLoad(function(){
  pane = dijit.byId("table-pane");
  add_elem();
});
function add_elem(){
  var node = $(".test tr:last");
  node.after(html);
  dojo.addOnLoad(function(){
    //Here I want to initiate any widgets that haven't been initiated
    pane.buildRendering();
  });
}</script>
```

How do I render the Dojo widget in the new table row?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ContentPane will render widgets in content set using *setContent*. You can, as mentioned,  also point the dojo parser to a specific DOM node after you've added nodes with *dojoType*. But if you're doing everything in code, why not use the programmatic approach instead of the declarative?

Using your example this becomes,

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.5/dojo/dojo.xd.js" 
      djConfig="parseOnLoad: true, isDebug:true"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div id="table-pane" dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane">
      <table class="test">
        <tbody>
          <tr><td>Name</td><td>Year</td><td>Age</td></tr>
          <tr>
            <td><span dojoType="dijit.InlineEditBox" editor="dijit.form.Textarea">Mike</span>
            </td>
            <td>2010</td>
            <td>12</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>

<script>
var html ='<tr><td><span id="target">John</span></td><td>2011</td><td>22</td></tr>';
dojo.require("dijit.layout.ContentPane");
dojo.require("dijit.InlineEditBox");
dojo.require("dijit.form.Textarea");
dojo.addOnLoad(function(){
    var node = $(".test tr:last");
    node.after(html);
    new dijit.InlineEditBox({
        editor: "dijit.form.Textarea",
        autoSave: true
      }, dojo.byId('target'));
});
</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

If you're using Dojo anyway, you can also you dojo.query instead of jQuery to locate and manipulate nodes. Ex,

```
dojo.query(".test tr:last-child");
```

Comment: I was having trouble with using dojo.parser.parse(). When I called the function multiple times, it was trying to instantiate new textAreas with widget IDs that were already used on the page.

Comment: Looks like my problem was with selector incorrectly selecting a widget that had already been rendered for rendering.

Answer (score 0):

this should help:
[dojo.parser.parse(domnode?)](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojo/parser)

But I think certain widgets like the dijit.layout.contentpane autoparse the loaded dom-fragment. the contained widgets have to be dojo.required before!